# My Ubuntu 15.04 won't boot, wrong magic number

Tags: boot, grub2, 15.04

So my Ubuntu 15.04 was working fine. Then I used clonezilla to backup the OS partition to a USB external disk.  Installed a new 1tb disk, then booted using a 15.04 Live USB disk and restore the image.  I then resized the partition using Gparted, and created a swap partition that was 16GB (I have 8GB of RAM on my lappy)  The first couple reboots worked fine and I was proud of myself of conquering this project like a boss.  Then I rebooted and got this error

error:  invalid magic number

error:  you need to load the kernel first

Press any key to continue

After that I am returned to the grub menu. I can boot from the 3rd option down as illustrated in the picture.

[image]

When I boot from the 3rd option, everything looks normal.  I am new to grub tinkering, but would like my system to boot like it previously did.....automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: Boot to the kernel .25, remove the other kernels, reboot and then upgrade again.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in a couple of weeks and regular updates this problem will fix itself.  I've seen this before a couple of times.  Something else you could try booting to this [Boot Repair CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).